# Laravel query builder (where) Поиск

Tags: php, laravel, запрос, builder

Почему Laravel query builder (where) не найден слово если там есть такие символы [/, -]
Пожалуйста помогите.

Мой код:

```
$columnsToSearch = ['code', 'oemNumbers', 'referenceNumbers'];

$searchQuery = '%' . $request->search . '%';

$products = Product::where('title', 'LIKE', $searchQuery);

foreach($columnsToSearch as $column) {
    $products = $products->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', $searchQuery);
}

$products = $products->get();
```

И данный с бд:

```
{"1":{"name":"A197J JS ASAKASHI"},"2":{"name":"SB2351 SCT GERMANY"},"3":{"name":"C 2513 MANN FILTER"},"4":{"name":"LX 1002 MAHLE"},"5":{"name":"AP 142\/2 FILTRON"}}
```

Comment: я не понял, при чем здесь поле name если поиск идет по полям 'code', 'oemNumbers', 'referenceNumbers' и 'title'?

Comment: Ну это один строка из таблицы "oemNumbers"

Comment: эти данные должны храниться в отдельных строках в отдельной таблице, а не в джейсоне

Comment: https://disk.yandex.kz/i/qXcdHg4IHjvJgA